# 的 at the end of the sentence (ex: 蠻有趣的)

Tags: grammar, mandarin

這篇文章蠻有趣的。
Why is there a 的 at the end?
Could anyone explain the grammar to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

的, when present at the end of a statement, emphasizes and affirms the truthfulness of the stated matters, and it also adds a positive tone to the statement.

- 這篇文章蠻有趣**的**。(Implication: It is **indeed** quite interesting)
- 她的車子是紅色**的**. (Implication: Her car is red **for sure**)

Note that 的 is often used after 是 to form 是...的 construction in Chinese grammar. See [here](https://www.chineseboost.com/grammar/shi4-de/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! You probably will not find a simple answer to the question: Why?

这篇文章蛮有趣的！(8 characters)

You can leave 的 off: 这篇文章蛮有趣！(7 characters)

You could replace 的 with 哦：这篇文章蛮有趣哦！(8 characters)

Possibly 8 characters have a better speech rhythm for Chinese ears.

有趣的 here is a descriptive phrase for 文章。

We could rearrange like this: 这篇有趣的文章 ....

这篇有趣的文章，讲述了一只小青蛙的故事。
This interesting essay tells the story of a little frog.

Two small examples of the use of 有趣的：

她在文章中提出了几个蛮有趣的观点。
In the article she mentioned some very interesting points of view.

Then you can take a descriptive phrase like 有趣的 and talk about it:

有趣的是，几周后本杰明再婚了。
Interestingly, Benjamin remarried a few weeks later.

You can't really take 有趣的, interesting, and use it that way in English:

Interesting is ...

Better to write:
The interesting thing is ...

Answer (score 0):

的 in 蠻有趣的 is an adjective marker

蠻 = quite

有趣的 = interesting

Some adjectives don't need an adjective marker 的, but some do

- **有趣的**文章 (**interesting** article) may be reduced to **有趣**文章 (**interesting** article)
- **為大學寫的**文章 (**essays written for** university) cannot be reduced to **為大學寫**文章(**write** articles **for universities**) without changing the meaning

> 這篇文章蠻有趣的

這篇(this)

文章(article)

(is)

蠻(quite)

有趣的(interesting)